# jQuery Cleditor get textarea value on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, onkeyup, cleditor

I'm using Cleditor http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/docs/GettingStarted.html. I want to get the value on keyup and insert the text into another div. cleditor comes with change() event that i'm currently using in the jsfiddle example below, but thats not the same as keyup. I want the div to be updated as i'm typing in. I tried keyup but it doesn't work.

Here's what i have now

```
$("#input").cleditor().change(function(){
    var v = $('#input').val();
    $('#x').html(v);
})
```

**Check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qm4G6/11/**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears that `cleditor` hides the `textarea` and replaces it with an `iframe` (see line 203 of cleditor source).

So to achieve what you want, you just need to access the resulting `iframe` contents:

```
$("#input").cleditor();

$(".cleditorMain iframe").contents().find('body').bind('keyup', function(){
    var v = $(this).text(); // or .html() if desired
    $('#x').html(v);
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qm4G6/12/)

**UPDATE to address Tim's comment**

This works in Chrome and Firefox (I don't have access to IE):

```
$("#input").cleditor();

$( $(".cleditorMain iframe")[0].contentWindow.document ).bind('keyup', function(){
    var v = $(this).text(); // or .html() if desired
    $('#x').html(v);
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qm4G6/26/)

**UPDATE 2**

User [ima007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977210/ima007) was able to find a better cross-browser solution: [jQuery Cleditor wysiwyg text editor: keyup() works in webkit browsers but not Firefox or IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864012/jquery-cleditor-wysiwyg-text-editor-keyup-works-in-webkit-browsers-but-not-fi/7864393#7864393)

Comment: This fiddle solution works in webkit browsers, chrome and safari, but not in firefox or IE, I haven't been able to figure it out but am wondering if someone can provide a code fix for these 2 browsers? thank you, -tim peterson

Comment: I answered your follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864012/jquery-cleditor-wysiwyg-text-editor-keyup-works-in-webkit-browsers-but-not-fi

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by slightly modifying the source code of the editor - 
in `refresh` method (line 801) I modified the blur event handler of iframe doc.

Previous

```
// Update the textarea when the iframe loses focus
    ($.browser.mozilla ? $doc : $(contentWindow)).blur(function() {
      updateTextArea(editor, true);
    });
```

Modified to

```
// Update the textarea when the iframe loses focus or keyup happens
        ($.browser.mozilla ? $doc : $(contentWindow)).bind('blur keyup', function (e) {
            updateTextArea(editor, true);

            if (options.keyup && e.type === 'keyup')
                options.keyup(editor.$area.val());
        });
```

and in the options that are passed at the time of initialisation, you can define

```
$("#element").cleditor({
keyup : function (text) {
 alert(text);
 // do something
}
});
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using of CLEditor '.doc' property?

> doc - The document object currently being edited in the iframe.
>   [cleditor documentation](http://premiumsoftware.net/CLEditor/GettingStarted#internalObject)

```
var inputDoc = $("#input").cleditor().doc;

$(inputDoc).keyup(function(){
    var v = $('#input').val();
   $('#x').html(v);
})
```

Comment: link broken, but, the [documentation](https://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/gettingstarted) also says: `These properties should be considered readonly.`.